# Is there an model validation attribute to check parameter types without using custom code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi where I want to validate if the used parameter is of type `int`. I know of the attribute `DataTypesAttribute` but it doesn't support the simple types. I do not want to create a custom attribute for this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49301360/custom-model-validator-for-integer-value-in-asp-net-core-web-api), as mentioned when you desalinize from a `json` string to object the value type must be `int`, if not the desalinization will fail. model validation as it's name suggests is mostly for domain driven and business related validations not type specific.