# Model Validation .Net Core 2.0 Web Api Not working

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, model-validation

I have a .Net Core 2.0 Web Api. I have various models with validation attributes on properties as such:

```
[Required]
public short? Quantity { get; set; }
```

I have an ActionFilter that checks model state:

```
if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
     context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
```

No matter what I do the ModelState is always coming back as valid when I purposely omit the required properties. My controllers are marked as:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
```

The models are getting deserialized correctly and I have the models parameters in my action methods marked with [FromBody]. It just doesn't seem to be running any validation (standard or custom). I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49300906/model-validation-is-not-working-in-asp-net-core-2-0) answer and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49301360/custom-model-validator-for-integer-value-in-asp-net-core-web-api/49305472#49305472) and several others but I just can't figure out what I'm missing. My APIs are protected with IdenityServer 4 so not sure if that plays into it but at this point I have to validate every action method myself which is not what I want to be doing. Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You have defined your Quantity as nullable short and also marked it as required so that is causing a conflict. Change Quantity to `short` datatype and then try.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood appreciate your response but If you look at the links I provided and also look at the code when Json deserializes an integer it will deserialize it to a default value (0). Since that is a valid int value it would pass validation. Hence, why I make my required variables nullable. Regardless, if I change it to int still validates as valid.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So my issue appears to be because I'm using `services.AddMvcCore()` and not `services.AddMvc()` I have to explicitly set `.AddDataAnnotations()` where this is baked into `AddMvc()`. `AddMvcCore()` gives you bare bones and you add what you need where `AddMvc()` gives you everything whether you need it or not.

```
services
    .AddMvcCore()
    .AddAuthorization()
    .AddJsonFormatters()
    .AddApiExplorer()
    .AddDataAnnotations()
    .AddMvcOptions(opt =>
        opt.Filters.Add<RequestFilterAttribute>());
```

Comment: Glad I found this. Been banging my head on this wall for an hour! +1

Comment: It absolutely helps. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

For required field validation decorate your function with   `[BindRequired, Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "your error message")]` instead of using  `[Required]`